# getting all child nodes' values of the current node

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve all of the values in the div. 
For example:

```
<div>xyz <span> abc </span> def</div>
```

This is the code

```
the_page="<div>xyz <span> abc </span> def</div>"
doc = libxml2dom.parseString(the_page, html=1)
divs=doc.getElementsByTagName("div")
print divs[0].firstChild.nodeValue
```

This only prints "xyz". I tried to just do print divs[0].nodeValue, but that gives me an error. 
I want all of the text. How would I get around this?

Comment: Please extend your question with the Python source code which returns the wrong value.

Comment: By "values" do you mean nodes or text?

Comment: If you don't get the answer here, ask the author of libxml2dom. See his e-mail address here: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/libxml2dom/

Answer (score 1):

for your:

```
divs=doc.getElementsByTagName("div")
```

use:

```
childs = divs[0].childNodes
```

then, you can crawl them. Each child contains a list of childs and nodeValue

```
for child in childs :
    if child.childNode == []:
        print child.nodeValue
    else :
        ## Recurse
```